# Tsung Load Testing for Ajax request

Tags: load-testing, tsung

I'm writing a config file for Tsung load testing the application. I want to write a request that can simulate clicking a button on the page. I know that this is usually done by something like this

```
<request>
    <http url='/' version='1.1' method='GET'></http>
</request>
```

But this link makes an ajax request and then return to this page so I'm not sure how to simulate this behavior. How should I go about this?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to look at all requests generated with your browser dev tools collection, like Firebug for example.
If you want to test an ajax call it's the same as calling a classical page for tsung, so first write a `<request>` with the url of your page, add a `<thinktime>`, and add another `<request>` with the url of your ajax ressource.

Comment: I opened the developer tool and saw the following when I click on the link generating ajax
`Request URL: http://localhost:3000/courses/860`
But if I go directly to the link it would fail because this goes to the action that has a `respond to` block and it is an unknown format. Will this behave differently if I put this request url `<request>` within the page '<request>` block in tsung? I don't know if this makes sense because I'm really new to front-end development ...